# Using Texture Paint output looks like cartoon. Can I rectify this?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm using Blender 3.4.1 and am doing a texture paint for the first time. The 3D model looks great in texture paint, but when I move to "Layout" it looks and renders like a cartoon. I would like to have it render out as the texture paint version looks. What am I missing?

Texture Paint Image that is good
[image: Texpaint]

Same image that is in Layout Mode isn't good
[image: Layout]

Comment: I think you're going to have to re-do that question. For some reason only one image is visible.

Comment: It looks like the "bad" image is from _Material Preview_ mode, while the good one is from _Rendered Preview_ (you can tell by the "background", or lack thereof in the "gap" on the floor). Any chance you enabled "Scene lights" or "Scene world" in the viewport shading properties?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to include the file itself. It can be found here: https://inlbox.box.com/s/p2k3x0nk0my31ouyidq6xq38x9cc2laz

Comment: the file link is not public but requires a login

Comment: Here the the public link to the file. Thanks all for your help; https://inlbox.box.com/s/p2k3x0nk0my31ouyidq6xq38x9cc2laz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first picture you are in *Solid Preview* display mode, this mode has its own way to display the texture when you are in *Texture Paint* interaction mode. If you switch to *Material Preview* or *Rendered Preview* mode you'll switch to another display mode that will take the material into account. Your material called *blue base* currently has an *Emission* node, it will emit light, you should replace it with a *Diffuse* or *Principled BSDF* node:

[image]

Once done, here is what it gives in *Rendered Preview* mode, if I put a *Sun* lamp (with a *Strength* of 4), this is the best display mode to evaluate how your object will look like once rendered (but note that if you are in Cycles it won't allow you to see the painting in real time, in that case switch to Eevee or use the *Material Preview* mode). As you see the texture is much brighter than what we see in *Solid Preview* mode, so you should not trust what you see in *Solid Preview* mode in terms of color accuracy:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much moonboots! I have no idea how that emission node got in there so I wasn't looking for it. I am so glad that you were able to figure it out for me.